# not getting previous month record using datepart in sybase

Tags: sql, database, sybase

Using below depart syntax to fetch for previous month record, it is working fine till previous year,however it is giving 0 value in January month.How can we get pervious month with date part even if year is change ?

`DATEPART(month(GETDATE()) -1`

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?)? assuming `ASE`, what you've posted is invalid syntax; please update the question to show a sample input and the expected output; it's not clear (to me) if you just want the month (as a number? a 3-char abbreviation? fully spelled out?) or a date from the previous month with today's numeric day-of-the-month (eg, today = `01/07/2022` => desired date = `12/07/2021`) and if this (`12/07/2021`) is what you're looking for then also explain what to do when the previous month does not have `30/31` days? (eg, `Mar` to `Feb`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that I used another type of DB, but I want to give a hint. I am using **sql server 2019**.

Firstly, you need to substitute date and only then take datepart from it.

Queries:

```
--dateadd -1 would subtract 1 from current month
--(Jan - 1 2022), would be December 2021
select datepart(month, dateadd(month, -1, getdate()))

--also date add covers internally the problem with 30,31 days.
--May always has 31 days, April 30. So -1 subtraction from 31th of May,would result in 30th of April.
select dateadd(month, -1, cast('2021-05-31 10:00:00' as datetime))
```